# Contradiction to Baire's Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, baire-category

My book states a version of Baire's Theorem as

> If $\{G_1,G_2,G_3,\ldots\}$ is a countable collection of dense, open sets, then the intersection $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty G_n$ is not empty.

I am having trouble understanding why this is the case. If $G_1=\mathbb{Q}$, $G_2=\mathbb{I}$, and $G_n=\mathbb{R}$ when $n\geq 3$, then $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty G_n=\emptyset$. This obviously contradicts the theorem.

Is my example invalid because $\mathbb{I}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are uncountable? The book uses the phrase "countable collection of dense, open sets" rather than "collection of countable, dense, open sets", which leads me to believe that the sets $G_n$ do not need to be countable.

Additionally, to prove this theorem the book says to

> construct a nested sequence of closed intervals $I_1\supseteq I_2\supseteq I_3\supseteq \ldots$ satisfying $I_n\subseteq G_n$.

Then it says to use the nested interval property to conclude that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty G_n\neq\emptyset$. But for $G_1=\mathbb{Q}$ there is no closed interval $I_1=[a,b]$ where $a\neq b$ such that $I_1\subseteq G_1$. This is because the interval $I_1$ will contain some irrational numbers, which are not in $\mathbb{Q}$. Thus $I_1\nsubseteq G_1$. Can someone explain and prove this theorem to me?

Comment: You need *open dense* subsets.

Comment: Precise statement in your direction is **in complete metric space, countable intersection of open dense subsets is also open dense subset.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The theorem does not hold in all spaces; I’m guessing from your discussion that here it’s specifically for $\Bbb R$, which is a space in which it does hold. Your example is not a counterexample: $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb I$ are dense, but they are not open, so they are irrelevant to the theorem.

You are correct in thinking that *countable* refers to the size of family of dense open sets, not to the sizes of the sets themselves. Indeed, *every* non-empty open set in $\Bbb R$, dense or not, is uncountable: it has the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$ itself.

Comment: So I can visualize $G_n$ as the entire real line with a given amount of points removed, or $G_n=\mathbb{R} \backslash E_n$ where $E_n$ is a nowhere dense set, correct?

Comment: @cheesyfluff: Yes, provided that $E_n$ is a **closed** nowhere dense set (since you want $G_n$ to be open).

Answer (score 8):

Your example is invalid because neither $\mathbb{Q}$ nor $\mathbb{I}$ are *open* sets, which is an important assumption in the theorem. You are correct that the sets $G_n$ need not be countable; in fact, since they are non-empty and open, they are *never* countable.